# Compare two files and store data in new file in python

Tags: python, file

Sorry, I have updated my question. I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt and their respective data is as follow:

file1.txt:

```
admin:admin
admin:meunsm
admin:12345
```

sequence in file1.txt is:

```
username:password
```

file2.txt:

```
192.168.0.114:1137   >   192.168.0.193:21 csanders:echo
```

sequence in file2.txt is:

```
source ip:source port > destination ip:destination port username:password
```

Now, what I want from python is to just compare these files and extract the username only. If username in file1.txt doesn't exist in file2.txt, then that username must store in a new text file. Here I have updated my question with .txt files data. Also there can be hundred of thousands rows in these both files and for loop should be use in this case because I want to save the username in my database table.

I have picked this code sample from Stack overflow Where both files are compared at same time, if there is any common data in both files that data will write in a new file:

sample:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt') as file2:
        newfile = open('newfile.txt','w')
        common_lines = set(file1.readlines()) & set(file2.readlines())
        for line in common_lines:
          newfile.write(line)

        newfile.close()
```

but my scenario is quiet different. I want if data in file1.txt is not in file2.txt then that data must store in newfile.txt.
Just I want to compare two files at same time and I want if data in file1.txt doesn't exist in file2.txt, so that data must be stored in newfile

Comment: You could use something like: "diff file1.txt file2.txt > newfile.txt" in the ubuntu command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple code and it will maintain the order (memory efficient), I will work on huge files also as it is using iterator

```
with open("file1.txt") as fp1, open("file2.txt") as fp2, open("newfile.txt", "w") as fp3:
    i = 0
    k = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if i == 0:
                # at first get line from both file
                l1 = next(fp1)
                l2 = next(fp2)
            # if both the line is equal get another line
            if l1 == l2:
                try:
                    l1 = next(fp1)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                l2 = next(fp2)
            # if line are not equal then put l1 in new file
            else:
                fp3.write(l1)
                try:
                    l1 = next(fp1)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
            i += 1
        except StopIteration:
            k += 1
            if k == 2:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

Comment: such a nice answer @Hackaolic but the last line has printed twice
xyz:xyz
xyz:xyz

Comment: Update my answer you can check.

Comment: this is the right solution but you have got one mistake, please remove : next to work break after except StopIteration:

Comment: yes removed that was typo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `symmetric_difference`.

Something like:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1, \
     open('file2.txt') as file2, \
     open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    diff = set(file1.readlines()).symmetric_difference(file2.readlines())
    for line in diff:
        newfile.write(f"{line.strip().split(':')[0]}\n")
```

**Note**: using `set` does not guarantee the order of lines.

Comment: dear @corralien I appreciate your answer. but I have another scenario that my text file holds data like this admin:admin first admin is username and second one is password but now I just want to save username in newfile.txt

Comment: my file1.txt looks like this:
abc:abc
aaa:aaaa
xyz:xyz

and the output is like this:
aaa
xyzabc
It is conflicting the two rows values in single row

Comment: Can you update your post with a sample of file1.txt, file2.txt and expected output please

Comment: your answer are not comparing right. It is just giving me the whole data. I just want only username of file1.txt which is not in file2.txt and nothing else

Comment: Obviously, the answer can't solve your problem cause it didn't well explained. I need to update my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy with a for loop.

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    newfile = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
    f1_lines = file1.readlines()
    f2_lines = file2.readlines()
    different_lines = []
    
    for line1 in f1_lines:
        init = False
        for line2 in f2_lines:
            if line1 in line2:
                init = True
        if not init:
            different_lines.append(line1)

    for line in different_lines:
        newfile.write(line)

    newfile.close()
```

Comment: your both answers are giving me two latest lines. It is not giving me the right answer

Comment: dear @Mirac I appreciate your answer. but I have another scenario that my text file holds data like this admin:admin first admin is username and second one is password but now I just want to save username in newfile.txt

Comment: So you just need to add another for loop to check each string for each user:password I updated the answer

Comment: what I do here is actually check each user:password in any of the lines of file2 if not so then I write it onto the newfile.

Comment: only username I need not password

Comment: you can also do it by just adding split function here but since you keep the value like user:password also in the file2 this solution also should solve your problem

Comment: then how to store these values in a variable

Comment: they already are in different_lines variable

Comment: dear @mirac I want to remove duplicate data in output file please modify your code for this scenario

Comment: or I have added a new question, please have an eye on it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040174/removal-of-duplicate-data-from-text-file-and-to-store-in-database-in-python