# Removal of Duplicate data from Text file and to store in Database in Python

Tags: python, file, filereader

I know that there are several answers regarding removal of duplicate data from text file but my scenario is quite different from these questions. In my case I have two text files, first one is 'file1.txt' and second one is 'file2.txt' and their respective data are:

file1.txt:

```
admin:2222
admin:meunsm
admin:12345
stack:0000
csanders:1111
```

sequence in file1.txt is:

```
username:password
```

file2.txt:

```
192.168.0.114:1137   >   192.168.0.193:21 csanders:echo
```

sequence in file2.txt is:

```
source ip: source port > destination ip: destination port username:password
```

Now, the situation is that I am comparing these two text files data in python and my case is if file1.txt data doesn't exist in file2.txt then new result must be store in newfile.txt and output in newfile.txt does contain only username and nothing else:

Here is the code which is used for giving me this output in newfile.txt

testing.py:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt') as file2:
        newfile = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
        f1_lines = file1.readlines()
        f2_lines = file2.readlines()
        different_lines = []
        
        for line1 in f1_lines:
            init = False
            for line2 in f2_lines:
                if line1 in line2:
                    init = True
            if not init:
                 different_lines.append(line1)
            var = ""
            for line in different_lines:
                new_var = f"{line.strip().split(':').[0]}\n" 
                var += new_var
                newfile.write(new_var)
            print(var)
            newfile.close()
```

Now, I want that output data in newfile.txt wouldn't be repeat at any situation. and the output should come like this:

newfile.txt:

```
admin
stack
```

Comment: And what is your question about this that is different from the questions you have already found?

Comment: yes, because In my scenario I am comparing two files but in other questions there is only text file and their results are stored in new file.

Comment: I understand, but you haven't asked a question yet. What do you want to know?

Comment: I want my newfile.txt output file doesn't repeat username

Comment: What went wrong when you changed your code so that it doesn't repeat the username?

Comment: it repeats the username, but I dont' want

Comment: I have mentioned my code above please edit the code where data doesn't repeat in new file

Comment: Why should `csanders` not be in the output file?

Comment: please have a look on file1.txt data and file2.txt data. my code is working like that if file1.txt data doesn't exist in file2.txt data then output must store in newfile.txt. In this scenario my code is working properly. But now I want if I have username twice or thrice in newfile.txt then it could not be repeat. Means duplicate data don't be repeat as I want result is mentioned in newfile.txt. Please have an eye on that also

Comment: Can you not use a set to eliminate duplicate usernames?

Comment: How can I use set kindly explain.??

Comment: dear @mkriege because csanders exists in file2.txt therefore we cannot store him in output file

Comment: Are you wanting to compare username and password, or just username?

Comment: this code already comparing username, just username. but I want if username repeats two time or more than this, then remove repeated username in output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type converting a `list` (in this example) into a `set` will remove any duplicate data (as commented by @mkrieger1), as duplicate data is not allowed in a `set`. Doing this before your comparisons will also help performance wise (in this example). So something like this might help you:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    f1_lines = file1.readlines()
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    f2_lines = file2.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(f1_lines):
    f1_lines[index] = line.strip().split(':')[0].lower()  # Just want the usernames
f1_lines = set(f1_lines)  # Remove duplicate usernames (if any) from file1 user list by type converting to a set

for index, line in enumerate(f2_lines):
    f2_lines[index] = line.strip().split()[-1]  # Get the username:password segment
    f2_lines[index] = f2_lines[index].split(':')[0].lower()  # Just want the username from that segment
f2_lines = set(f2_lines)  # Remove duplicate usernames (if any) from file2 user list by type converting to a set

output_file = []
for f1_line in f1_lines:
    for f2_line in f2_lines:
        if f1_line == f2_line:
            break
    else:
        # f2_lines iterables exhausted which means no match was found, so username goes to output_file
        output_file.append(f"{f1_line}\n")
output_file = sorted(output_file)

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(output_file)
```

Comment: Dear @bigkeefer really appreciate your answer, thank you so much for your answer